# JetBrains Rider remove highlight

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Installed a brand new version of Rider. For some reason Rider highlighs all the code in the methods (c#) - no matter what theme I choose. I've tried resetting to default to no avail.

[image]

How do I stop rider from highlighting 'background' in all of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the setting. For some reason I had set "Code coverage" on:

[image]